# after change my tableframe its start scroll horizontally?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I create a table view in story board. when i change my `tableView` frame it become horizontal scroll and stop vertical scrolling. i am using `auto resizing`.

Code on `viewDidLoad` for table:

```
 _inviTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
_inviTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_inviTableView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
_inviTableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
_inviTableView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
_inviTableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
_inviTableView.clipsToBounds = YES;

[_inviTableView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
 _inviTableView.delegate = self;
_inviTableView.dataSource = self;
[self.inviTableView registerClass:[inviYourBoastTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"inviCell1"];



 [self.inviTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"inviYourBoastTableViewCell" bundle:Nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"inviCell1"];

self.inviTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

`ViewDidAppear` code:

```
#pragma mark:didappear
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    orignalInviTblFrame = _inviTableView.frame;
}
```

Method where i changed my table frame:

```
-(IBAction)getYourTopBoastValue:(UIButton*)senders{

inviDetailViewDataIndex = -1;
inviTopDetailViewIndex = (int)senders.tag-1;
[_inviDetailTableView reloadData];

self.inviTableView.frame = CGRectMake(orignalInviTblFrame.origin.x,_inviSelectedView.frame.size.height, orignalInviTblFrame.size.width, orignalInviTblFrame.size.height-_inviSelectedView.frame.size.height);

_inviSelectedView.hidden = NO;


[_inviTableView reloadData];


 }
```

Note:`_inviSelectedView` is another `tableView`

Comment: stop vertical scrolling- increase the height of your tableview and check once for e.g orignalInviTblFrame.size.height-_inviSelectedView.frame.size.height + 100

Comment: @Anbu vertical scrolling working .  I am not changing height of the table just remain as it is. But still horizontal scroll create problem